# Processing apply protection on multiple ranges all together

Tags: google-apps-script, range, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet-protection

Recently ability to manipulate protection for a range programatically has been added. But is there a way to add multiple ranges all together when they have same protection to apply protection instead of processing each range one at a time? The following code is from Google sample script. Currently I am running the following code as many as ranges I have. Is there a better way to do it all at once?

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var range = ss.getRange('A1:B10');
var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');

// Protect the active sheet except B2:C5, then remove all other users from the list of editors.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var protection = sheet.protect().setDescription('Sample protected sheet');
var unprotected = sheet.getRange('B2:C5');
protection.setUnprotectedRanges([unprotected]);

// Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise,     if the user's edit
// permission comes from a group, the script will throw an exception upon     removing the group.
var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
protection.addEditor(me);
protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
  protection.setDomainEdit(false);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is a way for that, but you can assign those range values to an array and loop them and add protection. Hope that helps!

Comment: I am more concerned with performance. It appears to be slow to execute when each range is applied one at a time. So I was looking for a way to add all ranges to apply the same protection as a batch.

Answer (score 2):

The brackets[] in:

```
protection.setUnprotectedRanges([unprotected]);
```

suggests that an array is expected. Have you tried:

```
protection.setUnprotectedRanges([sheet.getRange("B2:B5"),
  sheet.getRange("F2:F5"),
  sheet.getRange("H2:H5")]);
```

Comment: I am trying to set protected ranges (not unset).

Comment: if you have so many protected ranges that is slowing you down you might be better off protecting the whole page at once and then unprotecting the ranges that you want to be editable. Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Michael, I was wondering how to remove protection from several cells at once and your suggestion made me think of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to manipulate non-contiguous cells in Google Spreadsheet (yet?), but there are optimiziations that can be done, setting the ranges asynchronously with HTML calls, threaded, protecting all then unprotecting some, all depends on your case, can you give an example on how your using it, how much cells you're protecting?

Updating:
To do asynchronous HTML calls you would first create a [sideBar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars) or a [modelessDialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showModelessDialog(Object,String)), and make a button that execute many [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myFunction(...)) functions. Since the code in the HTML page is asynchronous (it continous to run even though the function in google servers isn't done), you can make dozens of calls, E.G.:

In javascript HTML:

```
function protectOdds(){
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    google.script.run.protectCells( i );
}
```

This would run alot faster than calling trough the .gs code to protect one at a time.

Comment: I have only two ranges at the moment. When I used the sample code it appears the script execution was slow. It not a big deal at the moment. But it would be a nice feature to have. Do you have some resources that I can learn about HTML calls and threaded, ...

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little late, but here is what I did.

```
Var ranges = [ss.getRange('A1:B10'), ss.getRange('C1:E10')];
for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++){
var protection = ranges[i].protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
}
```